# copy row content in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have never done any excel vba program. I want to write a vba code which will allow me to copy a row including a button on the first column to a new row.

I am able to copy row content but not able to copy the button. Please help

my excel is like below:-

Button||DATA||DATA||DATA

image link: https://ibb.co/cijovv

this code I have written so far :=

```
Dim Lr As Integer
Dim newLr As Integer
Dim lim As String

Lr = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Searching last row in column A
newLr = Lr + 1
lim = "B" & newLr & ":" + "D" & newLr

Rows(Lr).Copy
Rows(newLr).Insert Shift:=x1Down
range(lim).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
Dim Lr As Integer
Dim newLr As Integer
Dim lim As String

Lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Searching last row in column A
newLr = Lr + 1
lim = "B" & newLr & ":" + "D" & newLr
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
Rows(Lr).Copy
Rows(newLr).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range(lim).ClearContents
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
```

If you have an ActiveX command button in A5, you may try something like this...

```
Dim Lr As Integer
Dim newLr As Integer
Dim lim As String
Dim oleObj As OLEObject, oleCopy As OLEObject

Lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Searching last row in column A
newLr = Lr + 1
lim = "B" & newLr & ":" + "D" & newLr
Rows(Lr).Copy
Rows(newLr).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = 0
For Each oleObj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If oleObj.TopLeftCell.Row = Lr Then
        Set oleCopy = oleObj.Duplicate
        With oleCopy
            .Left = Range("A" & newLr).Left
            .Top = Range("A" & newLr).Top
        End With
        oleObj.Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next oleObj
Range(lim).ClearContents
```

Comment: What is not working? I tested it and it copies the row with the button in column A provided Lr is calculated right.

Comment: for me it's not copying the button. and adding a blank row even if I am no clearing the content of those columns. Not sure what is happening

Comment: You are searching last row with data in column A. Make sure Lr is calculated correctly as I said earlier. As per your sample data if Lr is 5 then only the code will copy the Row5. Place a line MsgBox Lr just below the line where you calculate Lr and see if you get correct row to be copied.

Comment: I guess the problem is I am not able to place the button in a column. for example, here I am trying from A5, but that button is not there is A5. Not sure how I can add this button to a specific column. Will you be able to help me? I draw that button in Developer > Design mode

Comment: Before moving or resizing the button hold down the Alt key and then move or resize the button and it will fit in a cell completely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144684/discussion-between-iamnew-and-sktneer).

Comment: I have edited the solution considering you have an ActiveX commandbutton in A5. See if that works for you.